# How do you align elements inside a div inline?

Tags: html, css

How do you align those paragraphs inside the #main-informations div and the divs inside the #paper-scissors-rock div?

```html
  <div id="main-informations">
   <p>Score: <span id="score"></span></p>
   <p>You chose: <span id="user_choice"></span></p>
   <p>The machine chose: <span id="machine_choice"></span></p>
   <p>Result: <span id="result"></span></p>
   <p>Tries left: <span id="tries_left">3</span></p>
   <p>End result: <span id="end_result"></span></p>
  </div>
  <div id="paper-scissors-rock">
   <div>
    <img width="30%" height="200px" src="images/paper.png"/><br>
    <button id="paper" width="30%" style="background-color: black; color: white; border: 1px solid white; border-radius: 2px">Paper</button>
   </div>
   <div>
    <img width="30%" height="200px" src="images/scissors.png"/><br>
    <button id="scissors" width="30%" style="background-color: black; color: white; border: 1px solid white; border-radius: 2px">Scissors</button>
   </div>
   <div>
    <img width="30%" height="200px" src="images/rock.png"/><br>
    <button id="rock" width="30%" style="background-color: black; color: white; border: 1px solid white; border-radius: 2px">Rock</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div>
   <button id="restart" style="background-color: black; color: white; border: 1px solid white; border-radius: 2px">Restart</button>    
  </div>
```

Comment: Align HOW? Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: <p>s inside the #main-informations div should be on the same line and divs inside the #paper-scissors-rock should be on the same line too.

Comment: If they should be on the same line, are they really paragraphs? If not, don't use a `<p>`

Comment: Read about [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: You can use css display inline property

Comment: Thanks Arseniy-II, I used
#main-informations {
 display: flex;
}

#paper-scissors-rock {
 display: flex;
}

God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
#main-informations {
  display: flex;
 }
#paper-scissors-rock {
  display: flex;
 }
```